# Reporting services print layout can not show text box on next page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I use RDLC SSRS-2008.

In List Control I have a Textbox group.
When I preview, the Textbox is not show on the next page.
But the interactive view shows the Textbox on next page.

How can I solve this Problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your interactive page size to the same size as the printed page size

Comment: I Set Letter as Interactive size.
But it still Problem
Thank you.